# Bing Maps: How to use Navigation logic

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I would like to create a simple Navigation App. Therefore I used source from this tutorial:
[Calculating a Route Using Bing Maps SOAP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681887.aspx). With some changes in constructor it works on windows phone.

This tutorial shows how to calculate the route, but not how to use the navigation logic. And that is my question: If I am moving on the street, should I query each time when position changed the target and my new position? Or is there a better, more elegant way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having played with a navigation toy-app - I had some success by just making sure I stay close to subsequent points along the path and rerouting only when I stray away by a significant threshold. It seems like commercial navigation systems might be doing a similar thing and it worked fine for me.